# Referencing inner class in Android Layout XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having difficulty in referencing a sub class of another class which is a layout in my main layout XML file. I have the following class structure in my android application:

```
        public class MainClass {
        ....
        ....
            public class SubClassView extends LinearLayout {
               public SubClassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                    super(context, attrs);
                    .....
               }
        ....
        ....
           }
        }
```

And am referencing this in my layout like so:

```
<view class = ".MainClass$SubClassView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class
....
....
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class MainClass$SubClassView
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

When this class is not a sub class I experience no issues. Anybody have any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Had been trying to solve this issue for hours, but your code made me realize that I've got to use "view" with lower case and the correct syntax to write it in the xml. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Your `SubClassView` needs to be `static`, to be able to use it in your layout xml.

```
...
public static class SubClassView extends LinearLayout {
...
```